# Which datastructure to store logged in users?

Tags: java, gwt, data-structures

I'm implementing a web application and on the serverside I need to keep track of logged in users. I've implemented a simple Authentication class for this, with methods for logging in/out.

```
public class AuthenticationServiceImpl extends RemoteServiceServlet implements AuthenticationService {

    private final List<User> currentlyLoggedIn = new ArrayList<User>();

    @Override
    public User login(String username, String password) {
            // retrieve user from DB if exists
        // add the user to the list/set/whatever
    }

    @Override
    public void logout(User user) {
            // remove the user from the datastructure
    }
}
```

Now, I wonder which datastructure would be best to use? First I was thinking of a `List`, but as the order doesn't matter, and I need fast add/remove capabilities, I'm now thinking that a `HashMap`, using the `username` as the key and the `User` object as the value would be a better option. Any ideas/suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> as the order doesn't matter, and I need fast add/remove capabilities

You've got it, an HashMap would be the perfect choice, in my opinion.
Just with the fact that you can access a user object by its name, I think this is the way to go.